# Problemas al acotar consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla donde una de las columnas la uso para saber qué usuarios están suscritos a un hilo de un foro. Esta columna la relleno con los nombres de usuario. Por ejemplo el contenido puede ser el siguiente:

```
Paco; Pepe; Laura;
```

Si por ejemplo quiero buscar todos los hilos a los que Paco está suscrito, hago la siguiente consulta:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios  WHERE suscritos LIKE :suscritos");
$statement->execute(array(":suscritos" => "%Paco%"));
$todos_mis_mensajes = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero si por ejemplo hubiese otro usuario con el nombre PacoPepe, los resultados de la consulta serían incorrectos.

Con PHP puedo limpiar el array de forma fácil, el problema es que quiero cargar 10 registros por página, con lo cual haría algo así:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios  WHERE suscritos LIKE :suscritos LIMIT 0,10");
$statement->execute(array(":suscritos" => "%Paco%"));
$todos_mis_mensajes = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Necesito filtrar al realizar la consulta, porque si lo tengo que hacer después de hacerla, la cosa se complica mucho para cargar 10 registros por página.  Había pensado en guardar el ID del usuario pero estaría en las mismas con los ID 1 y 11 por ejemplo.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer un `explode()` al mismo tiempo que realizo la consulta? De esa forma no usaría `%` al hacer la consulta y me devolvería sólo los registros de Paco.

Comment: No queda muy claro el por qué utilizas '%Paco%' y de qué quieres hacer el explode. Puedes hacer un explode y guardar el valor que quieras en una variable php, y usar esta variable para hacer la consulta. De todos modos, el nombre no suele ser un campo único y por lo tanto no es el más adecuado, deberías usar el identificador único que tengas asociado al usuario Paco para hacer el select.

Comment: Uso `%Paco%` porque si usase `Paco` no me devolvería nada, puesto que siempre tendré un `;`, que lo uso para separar los usuarios. Hacer el explode antes no me vale de nada, no necesito hacerlo tampoco. Como ya he comentado usar el identificador tampoco me va a servir por la misma razón. @Carmen

Comment: Sigo sin acabar de entender la lógica que utilizas @JetLagFox, pero en cualquier caso creo que lo que buscas puede ser parecido a esto [https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928675/5675636], espero que te sirva.

Comment: sabes como empieza pero no sabes como termina por el punto y coma prueba `Paco_`, quitandole el % al inicio asi te aseguras que va a ser como empieza y agrega un `_` al final por el caracter de validacion en tu caso ;

Comment: @JackNavaRow ¡Gracias! Parece ser que funciona. Ponlo como respuesta para que pueda validarla.

Comment: Si quitas el % del principio puede que te funcione con el ejemplo, pero que pasaría con una línea tipo ( Pepe, Paco, Iván) ?  No localizarlas las entradas de Paco...

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas una consulta del tipo `SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE suscritos IN ('Paco','Pepe','Maria')`?

Comment: @Jakala He estado probando y tengo que quitarle el % que estaba usando, sino me estaría cogiendo los nombres que contengan Paco pero inicien de otra forma.

Comment: @AgustinM. ¿Qué ventajas tiene?

Comment: @JetLagFox las ventajas es que estás escribiendo **exactamente lo que buscas**, y no utilizas la cláusula `like` con operadores que pueden prestar a encontar tanto `123Paco` como `Paco123`.

Comment: ¿Tu tabla de suscritos tiene los nombres en una columna o tienes una columna "nombre" donde almacenas filas con "Pepe", "Maria"? La verdad veo poco clara tu estructura, por lo que cuando una estructura no es tan clara uno llega a tener problemas como a los que te encuentras hoy día.

Comment: @AgustinM. Tengo una COLUMNA que recibe el nombre de suscritos, dentro de una tabla que se llama comentarios.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61764/discussion-between-agustin-m-and-jetlagfox).

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente el código que funciona para todos los casos es el siguiente:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios  WHERE (suscritos LIKE 'Paco;%' OR suscritos LIKE '% Paco;%') LIMIT 0,10");
$statement->execute();
$todos_mis_mensajes = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Te falta un caso, el de "%; Paco". Así te cojerá el último caso